# How to get the delta between two date from the same column ? Power BI

Tags: powerbi

My problem is in the question.

Here, a picture of my column on Power BI:

[image: Exemple of my column]

My goal is to have an other column like this:

[image: this]

Is there any way to do this ? With Excel this is trivial but I don't know how to do it with Power BI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the previous row you will need to apply an index column when in query mode. Once you have an index column you will be left with your original datetime column and the index column.

If you then move to data view and add in a calculated column, to the pre-existing table, with the following formula:

```
IF('Table'[Index]=0,0,DATEDIFF('Table'[Column1],LOOKUPVALUE('Table'[Column1],'Table'[Index],
'Table'[Index]-1),MINUTE))
```

Please replace Column1 with your datetime column, alter the value that says "MINUTE" to the interval that you'd like to see the difference in.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! That is exactly what I needed !